# Polygon draw in ActionScript 3.0 - Vector.<Number> Vector.<int> drawPath() Flash Player 10 vs 9 error

Tags: actionscript, versioning, flash

I am working on a Flash application that draws polygons vertex by vertex line by line from a few tutorials.

The problem - I have it all working in Flash Player 10, but need it in Flash Player 9. When I convert it to Flash Player 9, I get these errors:

- AS_Classes\Polygon.as, Line 8 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Number.
- AS_Classes\Polygon.as, Line 9 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: int.
- AS_Classes\Polygon.as, Line 18 1120: Access of undefined property Number.
- AS_Classes\Polygon.as, Line 19 1120: Access of undefined property int.

  - How do I convert this to Flash Player 9?
  - Is there simple replacements for these? I think it is "drawPath()" that is Flash 10.

This, "var vertexList:Vector.;
vertexList = new Vector.(); " ... is also used throughout the code for "graphics.moveTo(vertexList[vertexList.length-1].x", although I think that "moveTo()" is compatible for Flash 9.

Part of the code throwing the first errors:

```
package com.AS_Classes {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Polygon extends Sprite{
        (Line 8) public var pathCoords:Vector.<Number>;
        (Line 9) public var pathCommands:Vector.<int>;

        public var fillColor:uint;

        public function Polygon(_vertexList,_fillColor=0x000000) {
            fillColor = _fillColor;

            (Line 18) pathCoords = new Vector.<Number>();
            (Line 19) pathCommands = new Vector.<int>();

            //first moveTo
            pathCommands[0]=1;
            pathCoords.push(_vertexList[0].x);
            pathCoords.push(_vertexList[0].y);

            //next LineTos
            for (var i:int = 1; i<= _vertexList.length-1; i++) {

                pathCoords.push(_vertexList[i].x);
                pathCoords.push(_vertexList[i].y);
                pathCommands.push(2);

            }

            //final LineTo
            pathCommands.push(2);
            pathCoords.push(_vertexList[0].x);
            pathCoords.push(_vertexList[0].y);
        }

        public function Re_Draw():void{
            this.graphics.clear();
            this.graphics.beginFill(fillColor);
            this.graphics.drawPath(pathCommands,pathCoords);
            this.graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think vectors are supported in Flash Player 9. A vector is an array that knows what type to expect, the type is specified between the carrots `<SomeType>`.

The simple solution would be to change all the vectors to simple arrays. So where you see something like `Vector.<Number>`, just put `Array`.

Of course, there's a performance hit.

Comment: Your comment about the performance hit made me do a bit of research, interesting, didn't knew Vector can be that much faster than Array.